# Change impdp directory on windows

Tags: windows, oracle

I am trying to import an oracle DMP file in windows.  I try this:

```
impdp me/pass@mydb file=mydump.DMP
```

I get this error:

```
unable to open file /rdsdbdata/datadump/mydump.DMP
```

Now I am on windows so I don't know where that cam from.  I also tried to set the directory like this:

```
impdp me/pass@mydb  directory=C:\Oracle fiel=mydmp.DMP
```

that gives me a "invalid directory" error.

Some research also said to try this in SQL:

```
create or replace DIRECTORY DATA_DUMP_DIR AS 'C:\Oracle';
```

but that also gives me an invalid directory error.

How do I import this file on windows?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, create a directory:

```
SQL> conn sys as sysdba
SQL> create directory dp_dir as 'C:\Oracle';
```

Grant `READ` and `WRITE` privilege to the user who is going to perform the import.

```
SQL> grant read, write on directory dp_dir to user;
```

Make sure that your dump file resides on the directory which is `C:\Oracle`.

Then run the `impdp` as:

```
impdp user@tnsname directory=dp_dir dumpfile=dumpfilename.dmp
```

Comment: Weird,  I am getting the same error when I run "conn sys as sysdba"